# Replicating Standardized Beta Weights Manually in R

Tags: r, lm

I am trying to replicate the following standardized beta weights output from the lm.beta library in R manually using the following formula: `b * Sx / Sy`.

```
# lm.beta output
             sce           ew
pl    0.04052626 -0.008595548
ed    0.07877526 -0.023042967
fins -0.09066186  0.062338676
hp   -0.11021743  0.181966171
```

The data for the replication is below.

```
# b
b <- structure(c(0.0502391680619868, 0.0693972485528214, -0.156313543659845, 
                 -0.271869666251473, -0.0183987350917768, -0.0117566158655761, 
                 0.185582953955953, 0.259951673424353), 
               dim = c(4L, 2L), dimnames = list(c("pl", "ed", "fins", "hp"), 
                                                c("sce", "ew")))
# Sx
Sx <- c(pl = 1.21, ed = 2.94, fins = 0.870000000000001, 
        hp = 1.05)

# Sy
Sy <- c(sce = 2.59, ew = 1.5)
```

So when I use the script below, there is a match for the second column, `ew`, but the estimates for the first column, `sce` estimates are way off.

```
b * Sx / Sy

             sce           ew
pl    0.02347081 -0.008595548
ed    0.13601861 -0.023042967
fins -0.05250687  0.062338676
hp   -0.19030877  0.181966171
```

I then used the following script, now there were partial matches for both columns (`sce` and `ew`) in rows `hp` and `ed`, but the other rows are off.

```
SxSy <- t(sapply(Sx, `/`, Sy))

b * SxSy

                 sce           ew
pl        0.02347081  -0.01484165
ed        0.07877526  -0.02304297
fins     -0.05250687   0.10763811
hp       -0.11021743   0.18196617
```

Comment: More information is needed. Does the dataset have missing data? If yes, the SDs of xs and/or ys which we get by sd() may not be the SDs used by lm.beta().

Comment: Knowing b, beta, and Sy, we can find Sx (Sx = beta * Sy / b). In the examples, Sx for ed and that for hp, computed (recovered) using the sce column and ew column, are identical, as expected. However, those for p1 and fins are not. Something's wrong. The Sx for p1 recovered from the sce column is 2.089267, and that from the ew column is 0.7007722. The Sx for fins recovered from the sce column is 1.502200, and that from the ew column is 0.5038610. They are different from the Sx defined above.